# protobuf incomplete type when passing a protobuf into a class member function

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

i'm having an issue like this:

people.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
message people{
    string name = 1;
}
```

then there is a class A:

```
#include "people.pb.h"
class A{
public:
  A();
  ~A();
  void getName(people p){
    std::cout << p.name() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

then clion keeps telling me the p variable:
Variable has incomplete type "people"

what should i do here?

---

oh i compiled the .proto file just as @Bart and @Botje mentioned.
BTW, i can do this with no problem:

```
#include "people.pb.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   people p;
   p.set_name = "hi there";
   std::cout << p.name() << std::endl;
   return 1;
}
```

as long as not pass it into a class member functions as mentioned in the second code block.

Comment: and i've tried to pass p as a pointer, void getName(people* p){std::cout << p->name() <<std::endl;}  still has same error

Comment: How did you compile your .proto file?

Comment: Yes like Botje mentioned. Did you generate the code using protoc and next compiled that code. `protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --cpp_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/people.proto` This will generate the code in `$DST_DIR` which in turn you have to compile using the compiler you use in your IDE CLion.

Comment: Please post the people.pb.h contents, there is no package definition in .proto file ?

Comment: @Botje i compiled the .proto file like Bart comment. oh and i updated my question. thanx alot

Comment: @Bart this is exactly what i did to generate the .pb.h and .pb.cc, and i updated the question, thanx alot!

Comment: @tunglt i do have the package defined in the real case, but here i just wanted to show my problem in a simple way. thanx alot!

Comment: You should make sure that the .proto file was compiled before the first translation unit that include the class A header file.

Comment: @tunglt  yes, the .proto file was compiled, and the .pb.h and .pb.cc file were also compiled into a static lib, linked with libprotobuf

Comment: @tunglt ah, i double checked my CMakeLists.txt file and turns out i did mess up with the compile order..i compiled the class A file before the .pb.h .pb.cc file. thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I messed up my build order.

so the correct build order for protobuf or grpc is:

- build the people.pb.h and people.pb.cc into a lib(say libpeople)
- link this libpeople with libprotobuf (or grpc++ if needed)
- build the file with Class A then link with libpeople.

big big thank you to @botje @Bart and @tunglt!